# Переворот блока на странице

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой перевёрнутый блок на странице, подскажите как его можно реализовать, чтобы обрезать на половину.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.top {
    padding-top: 175px;
    min-height: 800px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #8159c6 0%, #6c7cff 100%);
    
}
.block {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 660px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 153px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff9d66 0%, #ff7256 100%);
}
```

```html
<section class="top">
  <div class="block"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант использовать `clip-path`. Пример:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #8159c6 0%, #6c7cff 100%);
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff9d66 0%, #ff7256 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<section class="top">
  <div class="block"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

С помошью треугольников:

```css
.triangle-block {
  position: relative;
}

.triangle-bottom {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid green;
}

.triangle-top {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid red;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-block">
  <div class="triangle-bottom"></div>
  <div class="triangle-top"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9wna6x5o